# Python sybpydb.connect function cannot pass hostname

Tags: python, database-connection, sybase, hostname

I have a written a Python script which connects to our internal system to pull the data and that data it inserts in to a Sybase database.  The first step is to connect to the database by passing the database name, user, and password. I wanted to pass hostname and appname to the connect function but I don't think I can pass the parameters. Below is the function that I am using.

```
conn=sybpydb.connect(servername=os.environ["SERVERNAME"],user=os.environ["USER"],password=os.environ["PASSWORD"])
```

Similarly I have written a Perl script where it used ctlib.  Where can I pass appname and host name? Below is the function I am using in a Perl script.

```
**return Sybase::CTlib->new($user, $pswd, $srvr, $script, { CON_PROPS => { 'CS_HOSTNAME' => hostname}});**
```

My question is: do we have similar functionality in Python too? I am ok with any other alternative also. If anyone knows please let me know.

Comment: No not yet.  To use sybase.coonect I believe I need to install something.. I tried that but it throws error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to restructure you `KWARGS` and also ensure that the variable names are present in the `env`.
Try in this format of `KWARGS`

```
conn = sybase.connect(user='usr', password='pass', servername='serv')
```

instead of yours

```
conn=sybpydb.connect(servername=os.environ["SERVERNAME"],user=os.environ["USER"],password=os.environ["PASSWORD"])
```

If unsuccessful, can you clarify on the below point as it will help in locating the bug - ideally add some error trace if possible.

> But i dont think i cannot pass the parameters. below is the function which i am using.